# how to customise the print function for native objects in clojurescript

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I'm looking to customize how a react element is displayed, this is the code:

```
(require ["react" :as react])    

(defn react-element? [obj]
  (if-let [sym (aget obj "$$typeof")]
    (= js/Symbol
       (type sym))))

(extend-protocol IPrintWithWriter
  object
  (-pr-writer [obj writer _]
    (js/console.log "hello")
    (cond (react-element? obj)
          (write-all writer
                     (-> (js->clj obj)
                         (dissoc "$$typeof")
                         str))

          :else
          (write-all writer (str obj)))))

(react/createElement "h2" nil "Hello, World!")
```

I'm expecting the output to be

```
{:type "h2", :key nil, :ref nil, :props {:children "Hello, World!"}}}
```

but it still prints out the normal #js element:

```
#js {"$$typeof" Symbol(react.element), 
     :type "h2", :key nil, :ref nil, 
     :props #js {:children "Hello, World!"}, :_owner nil}
```

Is there a way to customize this behaviour?

Comment: it's an alias for react... I've updated the question

Comment: Why don't you use `(js/React.isValidElement x)` instead of your own?

Comment: @akond yeah that works. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause is that in the standard lib printing code, `implements?` is used and `satisfies?` is not used. This effectively limits printing overrides to things that are not native types. (`implements?` doesn't doesn't work on native types).

This may not be intentional and may be fixed with https://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJS-2812

Comment: ah awesome. that would be great.

Comment: Patch has landed and this should be fixed in the next ClojureScript release https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/commit/0773689ec748109a8c09ba924f90c25875eb6a9d

Comment: I'm not sure that it's working. Is it this fix https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/releases/tag/r1.10.439?

Comment: okay my mistake. i didn't upgrade the compiler. it's working really well.

Comment: Yep, this is now supported in ClojureScript 1.10.439.